# How can I do circle transform carousel with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, carousel, dart-null-safety

[image]

I want to make Circle Carousel Slider as pictured. How can I do this using CarouselSlider? I'm trying to do this but not all Carousel packages work this way or have a null safety feature.

Comment: I have a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68899357/how-to-customize-the-carousel-slider-in-flutter

Hope you find an answer. I started to follow this question.

Comment: I couldn't find any answer. I think i must wright my own component.

Comment: Have you try wrap the image with `ClipRRect` and use borderRadius??

Comment: @anandapramono I try but it doesn't help. I need different things which it will help all items like stack